# How to select only rows where a column value is present in an associative array?

Tags: .net, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, ienumerable

I can pass an `IEnumerable` into a PLSQL procedure using

> `Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter`

and it apparently converts it to an associative array.

What I want to do is take an existing query and wrap it in a select so that the only rows that end up in the set are rows that contain a value that exists as one of the items in the array.

What's the syntax for that?

Would a variation of `SELECT ... WHERE IN` do the trick?

Comment: If you know how to do it for IEnumerable wouldn't an array be the same?

Comment: maybe this example can help ? http://www.asktheoracle.net/how-to-convert-local-plsql-table-to-table-i-can-select-from.html

Comment: @Magnus I think you misunderstood me. All I know is the IEnumerable is converted to an associative array. I do not know how to do a WHERE IN using that array.

Answer (score 0):

If you could find a way to convert IEnumerable to nested table below example using [`TABLE()  Function` and `Column_value`](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=301) would work for you. 
Create a nested table type at schema level.

```
Create type ntt is table of NUMBER ;
```

And a sample code :

```
declare
  nt ntt := ntt(1, 2); --:= (1,2);
begin
  for i in (select rownum as id
                  from all_objects
         where rownum in (select column_value from TABLE(nt))) LOOP
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HERE IS = ' || i.id);
 END LOOP;
END;
```

Output is :

```
HERE IS = 1
HERE IS = 2
```

You could also populate nested table type from associative array inside a plsql block. This is the way which i know of using collection elements in `WHERE .. IN` Clause